# Удаление элемента из файла

Tags: python, файлы, list

Пытаюсь удалить определённый текст из файла:

```
                ind = text.index(текст)
                ind = int(ind)
                del text[:ind]
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```
    del text[:ind]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion
```

Answer (score 2):

строка - это константная величина, поэтому используйте другие функции для удаления чего-либо в строке, например

метод строки `replace()`

```
text = "abc"

text = text.replace("b", "")
```

заметьте - пришлось переписать строку, в исходной строке ничего не менялось

или если хотите использовать команду `del`, то превратите строку в список, удалите элемент и соберите строку заново

```
text = "abc"

pos = text.index("b")

arr = list(text)
del arr[pos]

text = ''.join(arr)
```

но это изврат уже, а зачем извращаться, если есть `replace()`?

можно извращаться и таким способом:

```
text = "abcbd"

text = ''.join(text.split("b"))

print(text)
```